# Saving queries and optimizing a database

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a script that is designed to query a list of posts by selecting a category, sub category and another sub, or by selecting all.

The problem is that when I want to show 'all' posts I need to create 3 queries for each post (to convert the category number into name).

Is there a way to make it more optimized?

Tables structure:

### posts:

- id (int)
- main_cat (main category) (int)
- sub_cat (sub category) (int)
- sub_sub_cat (sub to the sub) (int)
- description (varchar)

### main_cat:

- id (int)
- name (varchar)

### sub_cat:

- id (int)
- relation (int) (id of the main_cat)
- name (varchar)

### sub_sub_cat:

- id (int)
- relation (int) (id of the sub_cat)
- name (varchar)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to use join in your queries

Comment: Not sure about join? (quiet a newbie)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: At the moment the only way I know is to query each post, then take the categories numbers and query their table to get the name.

Comment: Do I unserstand you right if I think that you want a query to get the name of post with the names of the corresponding categories?

Comment: yes, I'm reading about MySQL join at the moment as suggested

Comment: Not a PHP question either, so PHP tag removed

Comment: Can you share more details, like the three queries that you currently use?

Answer (score 1):

Instead get all category name,id and store them into an array.Like [id]=>category_name.
And other query to get parent child , using joins.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT posts.description, main_cat.name AS cat_name, sub_cat.name AS sub_name, sub_sub_cat.name AS sub_sub_name FROM posts LEFT JOIN main_cat ON main_cat.id=posts.main_cat LEFT JOIN sub_cat ON sub_cat.id=posts.sub_cat LEFT JOIN sub_sub_cat ON sub_sub_cat.id=posts.sub_sub_cat
```

Will do it, but this is untested.

If you're going to be using databases, JOIN and LEFT JOIN are quite useful to have knowledge of!

Comment: I'm having one problem with that method I'm trying to solve. at the moment there is only 1 post, though there are 2 sub categories for the same relation, what happens is that I get the same post twice, just with different sub category

Comment: Should work as it will only use the posts that are made and join the data where that one post is - if you have multiple categories (which you didn't state) then it won't do anything about them - but I would have thought that each post would be unique (otherwise you have posts that aren't unique yet have multiple categories and subcategories). If this is the case then it's either database design or you would need to do another query, etc etc